# Just in mode (JIT) and POSTCSS setup not compile in Gatsby

Tags: webpack, gatsby, tailwind-css, jit, postcss

I want too just in time mode in my tailwind, gatsby setup with postcss.

When I run the `gatsby develop` it will give me following error.

Do I need seperate webpack file? I am very new in this so dont have any idea.

````
Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-postcss/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):

TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined```

Below are my config files.

`package.json`
```"@fontsource/poppins": "^4.5.0",
"@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.3.0",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
"gatsby": "^4.2.0",
"gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.2.0",
"gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^5.2.0",
"gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.1.0",
"gatsby-plugin-scroll-reveal": "0.0.7",
"gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.2.0",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.2.0",
"gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.2.0",
"postcss": "^8.3.11",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
"react-rotating-text": "^1.4.1",
"tailwindcss": "^2.2.19"```


Postcss.config.js

```module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a typo from the question but `Postcss.config.js` should be named `postcss.config.js`.

I'd recommend using:

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

To create directly `postcss.config.js` and `tailwind.config.js` respectively.

Your final configuration files should look like:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And:

```
// postcss.config.js
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'), 
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ],
};
```

npm commands:

```
"build": "npm run build:css && gatsby build",
"develop": "npm run watch:css & gatsby develop",
```

Assuming you've set up the `gatsby-plugin-postcss` in the `gatsby-config.js`.

> Do I need seperate webpack file?

Gatsby ships it's own webpack configuration so but if you need to customize it, you [can add your own to override the default one](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/). In this case (for using Tailwind + PostCSS) is not required at all.

There's a lack of details on the implementation but I'd suggest the following readings:

- https://madsbrodt.com/blog/tailwind-with-gatsby/
- https://medium.com/@mikeeeeeeey/create-react-app-tailwind-css-feat-postcss-631d9e33ba8c
- [How to get Tailwind.css working with Gatsby.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272554/how-to-get-tailwind-css-working-with-gatsby-js/48694033)